# Section 8 Halmos Naive Set Theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Not sure if this question has been asked before, but anyways. I was wondering if someone wouldn't mind clarifying what the question *is* asking:

> "Among the examples above, the inclusion maps are one-to-one, but, except in some trivial special cases, the projection are not. Exercise: What special cases?" -Halmos Section 8 Pg. 32

Just as background, he presents the the projection functions onto $X$ and $Y$ from $X \times Y$, and the canonical map; sorry, it is really a lot to write, but there is an [online copy pg.32](http://elienasrallah.com/dl/Halmos%20Naive%20set%20theory.pdf).

What I am most confused about is the inclusion map for the (seemly ambiguous) "projection". What I am thinking is $i: P \times Q \rightarrow X \times Y$, $P \subset X$ and $Q \subset Y$. However, the only way I could see this failing 1-1 is in cases $P \times Q = \emptyset$, yet I am not sure if that is what this question is asking.

EDIT: One of my biggest questions is if $i$ as stated above is indeed the "projection" inclusion map. It seems like it is not the projection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function with an empty domain is the empty function, and it is 1-1, vacuously.  (There are no two inputs with the same output!)

Comment: @Alan You're totally right, those were just my thoughts. (not good ones)

Comment: Yeah, I'm playing around with trying to find a special case where it fails to be injective myself

Comment: There are plenty of cases where it *fails* to be 1-1, e.g. $X=Y=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Oh, doh, misparsed it.  The inclusions are always injective. He's saying the projections are almost never injective

Comment: @Alan ooooooooooooooo. That make so much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order of increasing triviality:

- If all the factors of a Cartesian product are nonempty and *all except one* are one-element sets, the projection to the factor with more than one element is 1-1, but the others are not.
- If all factors of a Cartesian product are one-element sets, then all projections are 1-1.
- If any of the factors are $\emptyset$, the projections are 1-1 (vacuously: the product is then $\emptyset$).
- All projections from the Cartesian product of an empty collection are 1-1. (Vacuously: the product is $\{\emptyset\}$, but as there are no factors, there are no projections, so "all of them" are 1-1, as well as not 1-1, and equal to 17.)

These are the only cases where (some or all of) the projections are 1-1.

Comment: Just to clarify, then, Halmos was asking about $i:P×Q→X×Y$, $P⊂X$, and $Q⊂Y$?

Comment: No, he's talking about $\pi_X\colon (x,y)\mapsto x\colon X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_Y\colon (x,y)\mapsto y\colon X\times Y\to Y$.

Comment: In the exceptional case, only the projection to the only coordinate with several elements would be 1-1.

Comment: @dafinguzman Yes that's so. I'll clarify that.

Comment: By how is that an inclusion map?: Maybe this is where I went wrong....

Comment: It's not an inclusion map. He doesn't say that at all. When you originally transcribed it, you had it sounding like that, and maybe you're still thinking that, but it's not so and it's not what Halmos wrote.

Comment: @BrianO ......... that makes way more sense.

Comment: Good :) Just get rid of that "What I am most confused about..." paragraph. There are inclusion maps, there are projection maps; except in degenerate, $\emptyset$ cases, they're distinct things.

Comment: @BrianO Hey, thanks for your help, but I don't know if your answer is completely right. To see this, consider, without loss of generality $g$ the projection onto $Y$ and $X$, $Y$ such that $\{x\} \subset X$, $\{y\} \subset Y$. Then, $\{(x,x),(y,y),(x,y),(y,x)\} \subset X \times Y$. Thus, we have $g((x,y)) = g((y,y))$ but $(x,y) \neq (y,y)$.

Comment: I don't understand your example. What is $X$, and what is $Y$? $x\in X$, and $y\in Y$ is all you state. You haven't said that $x\in Y$ or that $y\in X$, yet you claim that both $\{x,y\} \subseteq X$ and $\{x,y\} \subseteq Y$ because of the pairs you claim are in the Cartesian product. So both $X,Y$ have at least two elements, $x$ and $y$, it appears. Your example is screwy.

Comment: @BrianO Woops. Gotcha.

Comment: or vice-versa ;) No problem. The 3 cases I mentioned in my answer are, I hope, clear. And for any group of sets that don't fall under any of those 3 categories, there will be two sets $X,Y$ among them that both have at least two elements, $x_0,x_1$ and $y_0,y_1$ respectively; then $\pi_X$ won't be 1-1 as $\pi_X((x_0,y_0, \dotsc)) = \pi_X((x_0,y_1,\dotsc))$, similarly $\pi_Y$ and any other projection won't be 1-1 using $(x_0, otherStuff)$ and $(x_1,sameOtherStuff)$ as arguments.

Comment: By the way, the same result holds for projections from Cartesian products of any number of sets, not just finitely many. Halmos introduces them later, using a by now nonstandard notation $\mathsf{X}$ rather than $\prod$.